# It is possible to have all the axes displayed in the ilnumerics surface plot without affecting the plot size?

Tags: ilnumerics

Say, you have a panel with hard coded width and height dimensions (preferably the width and height are equal in size). You want the plot to occupy that area. Without the axes displayed, the plot size is reasonable and satisfying. when the plot axes appear, they take much space and you are forced to increase the panel's width and height dimension which may not want you want to do. Is there away this can be done without the axes taking much space?

Answer (score 2):

The extend occupied by the plot cube data groups is controlled by the [ILPlotCube.DataScreenRect](http://ilnumerics.net/apidoc/html/P_ILNumerics_Drawing_Plotting_ILPlotCube_DataScreenRect.htm) property. It defines the *data* area of the plot cube rectangle only - ignoring the space used by labels and axes.

The DataScreenRect is automatically adjusted by default - depending on the sizes of axes (fonts, text heights), ticks, and tick labels configuration. By defining the DataScreenRect area yourself, you risk that some of these elements will move outside the visible area. Therefore, to enable optimal visibility for all elements, you may adjust the properties for label positions, and ticks as well.

DataScreenRect in the online manual:

http://ilnumerics.net/advanced-configurations.html

DataScreenRect in the class reference:

http://ilnumerics.net/apidoc/html/P_ILNumerics_Drawing_Plotting_ILPlotCube_DataScreenRect.htm

Axis Configuration:

http://ilnumerics.net/axis-configuration.html